# Dark normal map after exporting to .glb

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

I'm using [SimpleBake](https://blendermarket.com/products/simplebake---simple-pbr-and-other-baking-in-blender-2) addon for baking textures. In Blender everything looks okay but after exporting to AR .glb, the normal map causes black areas.
Image on the left is with normal map and image on the right is without.
Any ideas what is wrong?

[image]

Comment: Did you check the face orientation before baking?

Comment: Face orientation looks okay

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of experiments I finally found a solution. The color space of normal map must be set to *sRGB*. In Blender it looks wrong but after exporting in to .GLB the normal map is correct in the AR model.

Comment: Hm that's pretty surprising! The normal map is definitely supposed to be linear (not sRGB) in both Blender and glTF... it might be related to [glTF-Blender-IO#1473](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/1473), in which case converting the texture to PNG would also solve the problem.